# Under what circumstances can I divide work by heat capacity to obtain a $\Delta T$ value?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, work

It is my understanding that one can divide Work (in joules) by heat capacity (J/Kelvin) to obtain a Kelvin value.  Is this true?  If so, under what circumstances is this the case?

Comment: are you asking about how or in what sense is "work" equivalent to "heat", or what does this equivalence mean?

Comment: It's not clear, but are you asking if $W=C\Delta T$ can be true and, if so, under what circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are asking whether or not $W=C\Delta T$ can be true and, if so, under what circumstances.

Yes it can be true.

A change in temperature of a substance indicates there has been energy transfer to or from that substance resulting in an increase or decrease in the internal energy $U$ of the substance. That, in turn, is due to an increase or decrease in the average kinetic energy of the molecules of the substance.

There are two mechanisms for energy transfer: Heat $Q$ and Work $W$. Either one alone, or a combination of the two, can result in an increase or decrease in internal energy per the first law, which is for a closed system (no mass transfer):

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

Where $Q$ is positive if heat is added to the system and $W$ is positive if work is done by the system (e.g., expansion of a gas) and negative if work is done on the system (e.g., compression of a gas)

Consider a system consisting of an ideal gas. For an ideal gas internal energy depends only on temperature and is, for any process (for one mole of gas)

$$\Delta U=C_{V}\Delta T$$

If no work (compression or expansion) is done on or by the system, then $W=0$ and per the first law, $\Delta U=Q$ so

$$Q=C_{V}\Delta T$$

If no heat transfer occurs, $Q=0$, then per the first law $\Delta U=-W$. If the gas is compressed (work is done on the system) then $W$ is negative and

$$W=C_{V}\Delta T$$

An example is the adiabatic compression of an ideal gas.

Hope this helps.